# How to implement pause/resume button on CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple countdown timer app. I can start and pause the timer as well as reset the time but I cannot resume it once paused. I'm thinking a switch case will work better than the currently used if/else statements.

```
public void timerEnabler (View v) { 
    if (!activeCounter) {
        activeCounter = true;
        timeSet.setEnabled(false);
        stopStartButton.setText("Pause");
        rotateAnimation();
        countTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeSet.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
               timeRemain = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                resetTimer();
                MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm_sound);
                mplayer.start();
                backgroundImage.clearAnimation();
            }
        }.start();
    } else (activeCounter) { //pause counter
            countTimer.cancel();
            backgroundImage.clearAnimation();
            stopStartButton.setText("Resume");
    }
}
```

I would like the timer to continue and pause every time the user clicks the pause/resume. This is done by the same button. The second button relates to the reset of the timer. The desired time is selected by using a seekbar `timeSet`.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First you don't need the `else if (activeCounter)` you can simply use `else {`

Comment: I had another statement for the `else {`, my mistake for including it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this class for CountDownTimer always. source [bverc/CountDownTimer.java](https://gist.github.com/bverc/1492672)

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Andrew Gainer
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Adapted from Android's CountDownTimer class

package com.cycleindex.multitimer;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;

/**
 * Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with
 * regular notifications on intervals along the way.
 *
  * The calls to {@link #onTick(long)} are synchronized to this object so that
 * one call to {@link #onTick(long)} won't ever occur before the previous
 * callback is complete.  This is only relevant when the implementation of
 * {@link #onTick(long)} takes an amount of time to execute that is significant
 * compared to the countdown interval.
 */
public abstract class CountDownTimerWithPause {

    /**
     * Millis since boot when alarm should stop.
     */
  private long mStopTimeInFuture;

  /**
   * Real time remaining until timer completes
   */
    private long mMillisInFuture;

    /**
     * Total time on timer at start
     */
    private final long mTotalCountdown;

    /**
     * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
     */
    private final long mCountdownInterval;

    /**
     * The time remaining on the timer when it was paused, if it is currently paused; 0 otherwise.
     */
    private long mPauseTimeRemaining;

    /**
     * True if timer was started running, false if not.
     */
    private boolean mRunAtStart;

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture The number of millis in the future from the call
     *   to {@link #start} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *   is called
     * @param countDownInterval The interval in millis at which to execute
     *   {@link #onTick(millisUntilFinished)} callbacks
     * @param runAtStart True if timer should start running, false if not
     */
    public CountDownTimerWithPause(long millisOnTimer, long countDownInterval, boolean runAtStart) {
        mMillisInFuture = millisOnTimer;
        mTotalCountdown = mMillisInFuture;
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
        mRunAtStart = runAtStart;
    }

    /**
     * Cancel the countdown and clears all remaining messages
     */
    public final void cancel() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    /**
     * Create the timer object.
     */
    public synchronized final CountDownTimerWithPause create() {
        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            onFinish();
        } else {
          mPauseTimeRemaining = mMillisInFuture;
        }

        if (mRunAtStart) {
          resume();
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the counter.
     */
  public void pause () {
    if (isRunning()) {
      mPauseTimeRemaining = timeLeft();
      cancel();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Resumes the counter.
   */
  public void resume () {
    if (isPaused()) {
      mMillisInFuture = mPauseTimeRemaining;
      mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
          mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
      mPauseTimeRemaining = 0;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tests whether the timer is paused.
   * @return true if the timer is currently paused, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isPaused () {
    return (mPauseTimeRemaining > 0);
  }

  /**
   * Tests whether the timer is running. (Performs logical negation on {@link #isPaused()})
   * @return true if the timer is currently running, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isRunning() {
    return (! isPaused());
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
   * @return number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
   */
  public long timeLeft() {
    long millisUntilFinished;
    if (isPaused()) {
      millisUntilFinished = mPauseTimeRemaining;
    } else {
      millisUntilFinished = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      if (millisUntilFinished < 0) millisUntilFinished = 0;
    }
    return millisUntilFinished;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds in total that the timer was set to run
   * @return number of milliseconds timer was set to run
   */
  public long totalCountdown() {
    return mTotalCountdown;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
   * @return the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
   */
  public long timePassed() {
    return mTotalCountdown - timeLeft();
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
   * @return true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean hasBeenStarted() {
    return (mPauseTimeRemaining <= mMillisInFuture);
  }

    /**
     * Callback fired on regular interval
     * @param millisUntilFinished The amount of time until finished
     */
    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    /**
     * Callback fired when the time is up.
     */
    public abstract void onFinish();


    private static final int MSG = 1;


    // handles counting down
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            synchronized (CountDownTimerWithPause.this) {
                long millisLeft = timeLeft();

                if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                    cancel();
                  onFinish();
                } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                    // no tick, just delay until done
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                } else {
                    long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    onTick(millisLeft);

                    // take into account user's onTick taking time to execute
                    long delay = mCountdownInterval - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTickStart);

                    // special case: user's onTick took more than mCountdownInterval to
                    // complete, skip to next interval
                    while (delay < 0) delay += mCountdownInterval;

                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've seen this. I'm in the process of creating another app but I was wondering if my current code can work as is. i.e. if anybody has a solution.

Comment: I think you should complete your project ASAP with help of these type of working sources. You can just read it out for your knowledge and always reuse code to increase your productivity.

Comment: So, is it possible to add a delay before every resume ?
So what should we do if we want to add a delay before the time starts to decrease ?